# RKI_COVID19/FeatureServer - how to use that?

Tags: rest, api, arcgis

I am looking for a rest way to get more information out of a COVID19 map.

I noticed that arcgis provides plenty of topics and tutorials for developers.

I just don't know which tutorials are helping me to understand the FeatureServer.

I had two questions, can I query the below table with the rest api?

Like finding out what fields are in it, and what data.

If I have access to a serviceItemId - can I do anything useful with it?

```
 "tables" : [
    {
      "id" : 0,
      "name" : "RKI_COVID19",
      "parentLayerId" : -1,
      "defaultVisibility" : true,
      "subLayerIds" : null,
      "minScale" : 0,
      "maxScale" : 0
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I learned how to get the fields for the table:  RKI_COVID19/FeatureServer/0?f=pjson

Comment: Further reading found: https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/query-a-feature-layer/
Next step is finding out how the query parameter works

Answer (score 0):

Now I know how the query works.

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-related-records-feature-service-.htm

I found answers to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to access all data (`query=1=1`) in formatted son (`pjson`):

```
https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_COVID19/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&f=pjson
```

Or have a look at this notebook that implements the data retrieval from there:

https://github.com/starschema/COVID-19-data/blob/master/notebooks/RKI_GER_COVID19_DASHBOARD.ipynb

Comment: Thanks Tamas - I have a closer look into that github